# UWSGI specify socket location

Tags: bash, sockets, debian, uwsgi

I am trying to locate all my sockets logically and I am having a hard time understanding.

Say, for example that I want them in this directory: `/var/run/<app>/`

I should specify uWSGI this in a command line parameter

```
--socket </var/run/<app>/>
```

However in my `uwsgi.ini` I have this:

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
```

In order to get the effect I want, should I be doing

```
socket = /var/run/uwsgi
```

I am just confused, because one is an IP and one is a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc) you can use either [network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket) or [Unix domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) sockets.